# Class not found in Scala template with Play Framework

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a Play2 Framework application, and am having problem recompiling after doing a complete cache invalidating and restart in IntelliJ Idea. The error I get is:

```
[warn] Class models.AgeGroup not found - continuing with a stub.
[error] /Users/xxx/app/views/registrations/selectPrinterView.scala.html:13: not found: value AgeGroup
[error]             @for( (k, v) <- AgeGroup.optionsForGroups()) {
[error]                             ^
[error] /Users/xxx/app/views/registrations/selectPrinterView.scala.html:14: overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
[error]   (keys: Seq[String],args: Any*)(implicit messages: play.api.i18n.Messages)String <and>
[error]   (key: String,args: Any*)(implicit messages: play.api.i18n.Messages)String
[error]  cannot be applied to (Any)
[error]                 <option value="@k">@Messages(v)</option>
[error]
```

I think I had it before but cannot remember how to fix it. The second error about @Messages might be related and give a hind too.

This is my template code:

```
    <select name="ageGroup">
    @for( (k, v) <- AgeGroup.optionsForGroups()) {
        <option value="@k">@Messages(v)</option>
    }
    </select>
```

I use a class AgeGroup under App/models/AgeGroup:

```
package models;

import play.i18n.Messages;

import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created on 25/11/2015.
 */
public enum AgeGroup {
    U18,
    O18,
    BOTH,
    SPECIAL;

    public static Map<String, String> optionsForGroups() {
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> vals = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        vals.put(U18.name(), Messages.get(U18.name()));
        vals.put(O18.name(), Messages.get(O18.name()));
        vals.put(BOTH.name(), Messages.get(BOTH.name()));
        return vals;
    }

    public static Map<String, String> optionsForRooms() {
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> vals = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        vals.put(U18.name(), Messages.get(U18.name()));
        vals.put(O18.name(), Messages.get(O18.name()));
        vals.put(SPECIAL.name(), Messages.get(SPECIAL.name()));
        return vals;
    }
}
```

This has worked for me for two years, but now it stopped working, and I spend two hours and cannot figure out why (and haven't made a any changes to the code itself). So any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Need to `import model.AgeGroup` in the template

Comment: I now get 'object AgeGroup is not a member of package models'. I don't understand why it doesn't work after it worked all the time. Like it is not included in the build

Answer (score 1):

I used the command line 'Activator' and ran a clean there and compiled. Now it seems to work in both activator and IDEA again for some reason.